# Where can I find LEGO X-Pod Playoff rules and printoffs?

Tags: instructions, x-pods, play-off

Where can I find X-Pod Playoff rules? LEGO doesn't seem to be hosting them anymore.

Asked because of [this question.](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/615/are-the-x-pods-balanced) Hopefully it can be mirrored on a few sites so that it doesn't disappear again.

Answer (score 8):

[Here are the PDFs](http://www.host-a.net/u/pubby8/LEGO_Xpod_Playoff_Instructions_PDF.zip) donated by [Friend Of George](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/users/14/friend-of-george). [Here are the unit catalog PDFs.](http://www.host-a.net/u/pubby8/xpod_units_catalog.zip)

The starter kit for each pod has an inventory list, a set of cards containing units which can be built, and a set of X-TRA cards.  The cards and inventory list can be printed on card stock for better durability.

The Advanced Rules contain additional rules and Advanced X-TRA cards for the game.

The Advanced Strategy Guide contains some tips on how to best choose and use your units, along with movement and placement strategies.  It also gives sample sets of units and strategies for each Pod against each of the other Pods.

The boards were generated from the website with no obstacles for maximum flexibility.  Bricks should be used for these and placed where desired.

Comment: These PDFs appear to be missing a lot of instructions - the starter kit PDFs have only eight unit models but the advanced rules say each pod has over 25, from which you should select 10.

Comment: I downloaded everything I could find from LEGO at the time.  I must have missed something.

Comment: The Flash site had a "Units Catalog" with a "Print All ___ Pod Plans" button. You can still see the SWF at http://cache.lego.com/eng/flash/create/games/x-pod_playoff/xpod001.swf?sw20=http%3A%2F%2Fcache.lego.com%2Feng%2Fdownloads%2Fcreate%2Fgames%2Fx-pod_playoff%2F&sw2=http%3A%2F%2Fcache.lego.com%2Feng%2Fflash%2Fcreate%2Fgames%2Fx-pod_playoff%2F but the button itself is no longer functional.

Comment: @JoeWreschnig I seem to have all the models, however they are all very low quality black and white. Will post if nobody has the additional pdfs.

Comment: @Pubby: I scoured the Internet for over an hour today and had no luck. If those have the unit stats as well as the different levels, I'd say that's definitely worth the bounty. (The colors are weirdly off on a lot of the Play Off cards anyway.)

Comment: @JoeWreschnig You should post that cache site as an answer.  You can still download all of the rules and starter sets.  It's a shame that the units catalog is broken though.

Answer (score 7):

I found [here](http://www.bzpower.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=333028) a link to the [LEGO website on archive.org](http://web.archive.org/web/20060316215213/www.lego.com/eng/create/activities/playoff/default.asp) with the X-Pod playoff section intact.

The download links for the rules and starter kits still seem to work.

The units catalog is slightly broken, but I was still able to print all of the unit catalogs into PDF format using [PDFCreator](http://www.pdfforge.org/pdfcreator).  For them to print correctly, click on the Advanced Rules tab, then go back to the Units Catalog tab.  Click the button for the units catalog you want to print.  Select a unit from the list and click Print All Pod Plans.

The arena generator works also.

(Thanks to @JoeWreschnig for finding the cached flash file to give me the correct terms to search for.)

Comment: I did notice that the "Print all" option for the Wild pods seems to replace the last two (Vampire Bat and Wasp) with the last page from the Robo pods - did you see that?

Comment: Yes.  If you click the advanced rules tab, click on the Units Catalog tab, and then select the pod and click on one of the units of the pod, it will print correctly.

Comment: I have no idea how you figured out the sequence of menu clicks necessary to make that work reliably, but it does. Thanks!

Comment: Yep, it seems 3rd time lucky for me there.

Comment: @JoeWreschnig For me the last page was replaced by the Aero Pod's last page (which was the first unit I had clicked on).  I figured if I could reset the page somehow I could click on the unit I was trying to print and get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Recently, I found a link to a website that has everything the Lego website had in a PDF format. Here it is: http://korewanetadesu.com/pages/lego/xpod.html