# Where can I find Lego x-pod playoff pods for the game?

Tags: x-pods

I have some of the original pods but cannot find others, where do I get them? 
I would also need sheets for the things to build and their attacks.

Answer (score 3):

These are no longer in production, so your best bet to find the sets that you are looking for is [Bricklink](http://bricklink.com). Here's a [list of all the X-Pod sets for sale](http://www.bricklink.com/browseList.asp?itemType=S&catString=623).

These are the sets that were included in the game:

- 4348 Aero Pod
- 4347 Auto Pod
- 4346 Robo Pod
- 4349 Wild Pod

For building instructions, I'd recommend the instruction scans on Peeron. Take a look at the [X-Pod theme](http://peeron.com/cgi-bin/invcgis/setsearch?Inv=ANY&Inst=ANY&Thumbs=NO&ID=&Name=&Theme=x-pods&YearS=&YearE=&PcsS=&PcsE=&FigsS=&FigsE=&MSRPS=&MSRPE=) there.

Here are the [instructions for the game](http://host-a.net/u/pubby8/LEGO_Xpod_Playoff_Instructions_PDF.zip). See [this question](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/641/where-can-i-find-lego-x-pod-playoff-rules-and-printoffs?rq=1) for more information on those.

Comment: There was an X-pod game?! I have to admit finding them late, but wow... a game?

Comment: Considering the x-pods didn't use too specific parts, it's possible you can build them using parts from recent sets.