# How can I make a Lego heroica scale gladiator arena?

Tags: building, heroica

Sorry all my questions are about heroica, but this needs to be easy so that I can build in a few mins. I will make gladiator micro figures as well, if someone can make a **Lion** too!

Comment: Which size are you aiming at?

Comment: @Joubarc - I'd assume Heroica/Microfig scale.

Answer (score 5):

Let's assume that the Heroica figures are exactly half the scale of the normal LEGO minifigure.  That would be roughly 1:100.  At that scale, 1 meter would be roughly 0.75 studs long or the height of a standard LEGO brick.

Now let's convert the Coliseum dimensions:

- Height: 50 meters  ~ 50 bricks high
- Length: 189 meters ~ 142 studs
- Width: 156 meters ~ 117 studs

To calculate the real dimensions of this LEGO construction, let's [remember](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/288/what-are-the-dimensions-of-a-lego-brick/298#298) that a brick is 9.6mm high and the distance for 1 stud is 8mm (= 1 stud radius + the distance between two studs).

Using these values we get:

- Height: 50 bricks = 480mm (~18.9 inches)
- Length: 142 studs = 1136mm (~44.7 inches)@
- Width: 117 studs = 936mm (~36.9 inches)@

@*Those two distances are calculated by multiplying 6.4mm with the number of studs, and then adding 1.6mm for the last little bit of beam left after the last stud.*

Comment: The distance for one stud is 8mm (2 times the radius plus the distance between them). For example, a 1x1 brick is 8mm square, while a 1x2 brick is 16mm the long way. That is why 5 plates equals 2 studs: 5 x 3.2mm = 2 x 8mm = 16mm.

Comment: @oddtodd You are totally right and I have made the fix.  I have no idea where that 6.4mm came from.  Thanks for caching this mistake. (...and I'm like, I need a coffey)

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need a lot of pieces. And I don't know if you are talking about making it for your game boards or for your minifigures. I, the LEGO know-it-all, will help you out. I have made a ton of things, including a LEGO to-scale tennis court. That was fairly easy and I made it in about 3–4 hours.

So, if you want to make an arena, you first have to make a square- or circle-sized, box-like base with walls. Make four walls and put them all together as if you were making a house.

Then, make some stands. These will be supported by poles or stacked bricks ot have the height over the wall. This will take a lot of pieces, but very basic ones. What you want to do is use long skinny 2×12 or 2×10, or any longer plank, and 2×4 bricks, and you will want to build some seats or bleachers with those. I will upload a pic of those soon.

Then, you want to kind of make a roof over those bleachers. And of course you also want some entrances and maybe a gate or tunnel. Then you can use the bear from LEGO forest police, make some chariots, and have fun.