# Who else produces Duplo-sized blocks?

Tags: compatibility, 3rd-party, duplo

I gather that Mega Bloks Mini Bloks are the same size as Duplo, and are compatible with it. Do any of the other major brick manufacturers make similar bricks?

Knowing the possibilities can help when sorting out collections of bricks purchased second hand.

Comment: UNICO PLUS! By Androni Giacolotti

Comment: I've Mega Bloks compatible with Duplo & others only if on top. Are yours fully compatible?

Answer (score 6):

There are several Chinese companies making DUPLO clones, many are listed in this fascinating article by Anthony Tomkins of UK LUG The Brickish Association.

[Communist LEGO, a review of some Chinese copies](http://uploads.brickset.com/docs/clonebrands_v1.6.pdf)

Comment: The above link no longer works, but [archive.org has a copy](http://web.archive.org/web/20151007080639/http://www.1000steine.com/brickset/miscellaneous/clonebrands.pdf).

Answer (score 4):

Coko definitely does (See here: http://www.edex.com.au/coko-baby-blocks-transport-set-26-pieces.html). Not sure in which countries they are available.

There is another question around about a mystery company with an umbrella/smiley/anchor logo on the studs. I've only found System-size bricks and plates from them, but the asker implied she had found Duplo-sized bricks as well. ([Third-party blocks with a smiling face or an umbrella with 2 dots on each side](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/2226/real-duplos-vs-megabloks))

Answer (score 3):

We own Polish Wader's "mini block" set. It is mostly compatible with DUPLO, yet some combinations of "foreign" blocks stick poorly to each other. WADER bricks have octagon studs and their logo imprinted.

Also, Ukrainian Tigres produces some simple brick sets http://tigres.com.ua/catalogue/plastmassovye-igrushki/konstruktory/konstruktor-122-el/ The forms of these are copied from WADER. However, their studs are round.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but someone out there might be Googling this like I did. A Chinese made one "HongYuanSheng" matches perfectly.

[image: example product]

Answer (score 2):

A short time ago I bought a marble run from **[Hubelino](https://www.hubelino.de/produkte/hubelino/kugelbahn/)** because they are compatible with Duplo. I bought a set without bricks, so I can not tell anything about the bricks they also sell.
The tracks match very well and give a lot of fun.

Comment: I can confirm that the Hubelino blocks & track segments are compatible with Duplo.

Answer (score 1):

In older secondhand duplo sets, I've often come across Tyco brand blocks. They are easy to tell apart because they have flat tops on the studs and the plastic is often imprinted with the brand name somewhere.

K'Nex makes some "Kid K'Nex" sets with sesame street themes that come with blocks that look a lot like duplos as well. But the heights of the bricks and studs do not match, so they're very easy to tell they aren't duplo as well.

Answer (score 1):

I saw these on Amazon.  They have great reviews, but not sure about them yet: 
500 piece DELUXE Basic set of Duplo compatible Building bricks 
by Smart Builder Toys 
Link: https://amzn.com/B016DQLQ20