# Identification of rare LEGO DUPLO piece

Tags: part-identification, duplo

Can you please help me identify what is this LEGO DUPLO cube?
I received it inside package of old cubes I bought. It has shorter studs than normal ones, seems quite old.
Material and its firmness makes me think that it is probably original DUPLO.
I am very curious if it some of older piece or if it is just some "reject piece".

The size of label inside studs is "LEGO" and its larger than labels "LEGO" or "DUPLO" inside my other cubes.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5):

According to [this post](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/1588/what-are-the-exact-dimensions-of-a-duplo-brick) from 2012, the studs on Duplo bricks were changed somewhere in the 90s to be taller and have thinner walls.

Your brick is a genuine Duplo brick, it's just old.