# Any elements that can be connected to the cavity under a stud?

Tags: compatibility

Are there any elements that can be connected to the 'cavity' (i.e. the space) under a stud (e.g. on a regular plate or a regular brick)? The cavity measures about 2.4mm in diameter.

So far I've only tried a minifig hand peg (not the clip side, the other side) but unfortunately it is just a bit smaller, it has a diameter of about 2.3mm.

**[Edit]** I'm talking about the cylindrical cavity with a diameter of 1.5 LU as indicated in the overview posted here -- [What are the dimensions of a LEGO brick?](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/288/what-are-the-dimensions-of-a-lego-brick).

Answer (score 3):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you're talking about the molding cavity directly underneath the stud (that actually goes up into the stud), and not the main tube cavities under plates/bricks (that are actually offset from the studs).

If that's the case, no, I'm not aware of any element that "intentionally" fits that space.

First off, I don't think that space is made with a high tolerance.  Looking at some of my bricks, the dimensions of that cavity are not nearly as uniform as the other features of the brick.

Secondly, I don't know how many System bricks have components that are not integer multiples of LUs.

You might get lucky and get a minifigure piece that has a detail that is 1.5 LUs, but you'd have to try a lot of them.

Comment: Your interpretation is correct :). Hmm, the part about the tolerance is interesting. I was hoping to fit a "Hand Pirate Hook" in the cavity, sounds like there's still some hope.

Answer (score 1):

Without further specification, unless I read your question wrong, ANY normal brick-type element can be connected to the cavity under a stud - the whole principle that LEGO was based on, basically. Anything that has a stud on it will fit.

If you rather meant "non-stud" elements such as hands, signs, rods, etc., please update the question to make it more specific.

Comment: Updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

For base plates you can connect the light sabre pieces underneath the base plate but I don't think it was an intentional feature

Answer (score 0):

*(Edit: after re-reading your question I realized I misinterpreted the stud with the bar. Leaving the answer for posterity.)*

There is. The size in the small holes beneath newer plates is the same size as a connector that doesn't have a fixed name. Bricklink calls it pin, others call it mini pin or stub. It is used in minifig headgears and a few other places, like the old dragon flame. It's not a connection people often use, but it can be done:

[image: Using the mini pin]

This picture is taken from [a small writeup](http://www.dagsbricks.com/2013/04/lego-tips-and-techniques-mini-pin.html) by Brian D'Agostine which documents other uses of it. You can also use the same pin (stub, mini pin, teensy tiny peg) to [create fire strands](http://www.classic-castle.com/howto/articles/firestrands.html):

[image]

Once you're aware of the connection you can find many fun fits for it.