# What is the purpose of this plate with door rail?

Tags: piece-information

I'm looking at the this piece:

[image: 4510]

Is this piece some kind of a track on which you can build stuff that slides? I see it in sets as a decorative piece from time to time. What does "door rail" even refer to?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

These pieces are frequently used for decoration now, but they were originally used for sliding doors, particularly on train sets. Here's one of the first uses from set 7838 in 1983:

[image: 7838 page 8]
[image: 7838 page 9]

While they could be used in structures, these were frequently used for putting doors on the train cars themselves:

[image: 7727 page 18]

These parts can also be used to create tracks for other things that need to slide as shown in Container Loading Crane (7823):

[image: 7823 page 4]

This class of part also has a 2xn variety that now allows whole 1xn bricks to slide within it:

[image: 30586]

This is useful for building sliding doors and walls that are a full module wide. Here's an example from 31009:

[image: 31009]

Answer (score 15):

In addition to what jncranton wrote, the plate with the rail is a perfect fit for sliding in the [brick with groove](http://rebrickable.com/parts/2653):

[image]

You can see an example of that technique in the [Cloud City](http://peeron.com/scans/10123-1) set:
[image]

Comment: And the 2 stud version was often used to secure the old 9V motor (http://www.bricklink.com/PL/71427c01.gif?0) that had two grooves on each sides, allowing it to be removed easily.

Answer (score 0):

It can also be used as the eave of a building!