# What is the wall thickness of a lego brick?

Tags: piece-information, design, size, bricks-and-pieces

Different sources show different thickness for the wall. I've seen everywhere from 1.0mm to 1.8mm. I need to know with a high degree of confidence since I'm making an aluminium lego piece of a school assignment, so my wall thickness will be smaller.  Because I only get to have one attempt, I can't try it with one piece and adjust the model for a second run.

The image below shows the dimension in question, with this drawing taken from another SE question, made by SE user Bartneck
[image: drawing of a lego brick]
Original source: https://bricks.stackexchange.com/a/11131

Comment: Hi Mark, the [top-voted answer](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/a/295/56) in the question this image came from gives the dimension of the wall of a 1x1 brick as 1.6mm, while the technical drawing this came from was actually in mm, so the wall thickness there is 1.2mm.

Comment: Considering your very specific needs, you might want to get the actual brick you're going to duplicate and use calipers to measure it exactly

Comment: The precision I need would need an anvil micrometer, which i don't have :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/a/295/56), a 1x1 brick has walls 1.6mm thick - this fits in with the base unit of 0.8mm that is used throughout all LEGO elements, as per [pcantin's answer](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/a/11131/56) on the same question.

The 1x4 brick in the image you've included shows walls of 1.2mm, while a similar drawing on [bartneck's site](http://www.bartneck.de/2019/04/21/lego-brick-dimensions-and-measurements/) for the 1x4 Technic Brick with Holes shows a wall thickness of 1.5mm, which is closer to the expected 1.6mm. Curiously the Stud diameter is exactly as expected at 4.8mm.