# What is LEGO terminology for measurement of normal bricks and common scales?

Tags: piece-information, terminology, scale

Where can I find basic LEGO terminology illustrated with LEGO parts, e.g. what's a stud? What's a plate? I also need to know the names of the most common scales of basic LEGO kits, and measurement of a most fundamental part(s) at each scale.

Comment: Does the answer below satisfy you, or do you need more information?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Terminology

This is the most basic terminology in a single image: 
[image]

A bit more verbose version is found in [this slideshow](https://www.slideshare.net/merrywillis/lego-we-do-parts-vocabulary), but there are a few factual errors, highlighted in the comments below.

The various parts are named based on their main characteristics, then their sizes in studs, as seen here: [image]

After getting the hang of it, it's time to advance to the more complex terminology, with the help of the indispensable blog [New Elementary](http://www.newelementary.com/p/glossary.html).

### Measurements

The fundamental sizes for the basic bricks are seen in [this answer](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/a/298/3631), or a bit more simply: [image]

The height of the plates is 1/3 of the bricks, or 3.2 mm.

### Scale

As for scales, this question is a bit complicated, as the basic reference unit is the LEGO Minifigure, which has weird proportions, resulting in inconsistent scales:[image]

However, there are a few official ones, including:

- minifigure scale (about 1:40)
- microscale: anything way smaller than that, see [these examples](https://web.archive.org/web/20120621011656/http://62bricks.com:80/micro-scale-lego-building) or [these official ones](https://brickset.com/sets/tag-Microscale).
- midi-scale was only ever used officially for [two sets](https://brickset.com/sets/tag-Midiscale), which are sized very differently, as both models are around 30 studs long, so it's 1:100 - 1:6000 which would definitely fall into microscale category.
- towards the other end of the scale, there is life-sized, which of course does not get used much for official sets for sale, but rather for one-off projects: [image]
- and it is definitely possible to create larger than life LEGO builds: [image] Or models of microscopical structures, like cells: [image] or even of subatomic scale: [image]

Comment: I believe "technic linkers" are more commonly called "pins".

Comment: Also worth mentioning is the term “antistud”, which is the opening at the bottom of a brick/plate/tile that fits a stud snugly and is the reason the LEGO brick system works so well.

Comment: @PhilB. I have updated the images with your suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

From the book [Crazy Action Contraptions](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?B=9781591747697) page 47 has a nice graphic showing the relation between the sizes of different pieces.

[image: page 47 of Crazy Action Contraptions]

I'd add that it is more common to call a "sideways brick" a stud. All lego elements are measured in studs. Using the same example as on the far right of the image, this [Technic Axle](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3705) is four studs long.