# What is the dimensions of lego spike motor?

Tags: motor, powered-up, spike-prime, lego-dimensions

Any Ideas on what is the dimensions of this motor,
and the holes and space between them? [image: Lego Spike Motor]

Comment: Do read https://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/288/13403 - all lengths can be derived from those. e.g. the diameter of a stud (or a technic hole) is 4.8mm, and the distance between studs is (or between technic holes) is 8mm.

Answer (score -1):

SPIKE M:  2.38 x 3.7 x 7.88 cm

SPIKE L: 8 x 4 x 4 cm

Comment: Thanks,what are the diameter of the holes and space between them?

Comment: @AbdElhaleem, well dimensions are there, so it is easy to do the math if you have any LEGO bricks on hand. Diameter - one stud. Distance - 2 bricks (center to center), 3 bricks (edge to edge).

Comment: ok, i used BL studio for later for correct dimetions

Comment: What does Spike L motor has to do with regards to OP's question? The M motor is clearly higher than 3 studs - rotating part is not part of motor's dimensions?

Comment: the rotating part is one stud height.

Comment: The rotating piece is still part of a motor and its dimensions, right?

Comment: yep. i do a quick update to this answer :)

Comment: Well, I don't have any parts in hands, so I need to know the dimensions in mm, sorry for asking a lot

Comment: OK, 8 mm is 1 stud.

Comment: Did you measure your own motors to get these values? Or did you find them somewhere?

Comment: I used BrickLink.com

Comment: There is a place for improvement. Why are there two motos listed? Which one of them is on OP's picture? Why dimensions for each motor are provided in different units?